# Problema com Google Maps quando crio .apk

Tags: android, apk

Estou criando um app para Android que utiliza o Google Maps API.
Só que estou tendo problemas quando eu crio o .apk e instalo no celular, está dando esse erro:

```
09-18 16:05:07.631  18129-18238/com.anderson.app E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

Mas se eu rodo executando direto pelo Android Studio para o celular está funcionando perfeitamente.

OBS: Quando eu  criei o SHA1 para colocar la no google console eu fiz assim:

```
keytool -list -keystore C:\Users\Anderson\AndroidStudioProjects\Lisandro\android.jks
```

Isso serve tanto para debug como para release?

Mais algumas informações...

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        android {
            keyAlias 'android'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/Anderson/AndroidStudioProjects/Lisandro/android.jks')
            storePassword 'android'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:19'
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.anderson.lisandro'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.android
            debuggable false
            jniDebugBuild false
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.android
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.anderson.lisandro" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--\\
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyA1ad9...lO5pAoidaVA" />
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Dados do Google Console

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso é tudo! kkk

Alguém já passou por isso?

Obrigado!

Comment: Quando eu roda pela .apk da o seguinte erro: 
09-18 12:03:23.691  13868-14048/com.anderson.app I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
09-18 12:03:23.691  13868-14048/com.anderson.app E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

Quando eu rodo direto pelo Android Studio funciona normalmente. mas quando eu gero o .apk da esse erro ai, por que será?

Comment: Cara, verifica como tá o nome do seu pacote no Android Studio. Quando fui implementar o Google Maps, eu apanhei MUITO e depois de muito penar eu prestei atenção que o package gerado é `com.seupackage.debug`. Adicionei o .debug  no console e funcionou lindamente. Verifique este ponto! DETALHE IMPORTANTE: desinstale totalmente o app do celular/emulador antes de testar

Comment: Mas no modo debug funciona perfeitamente, o problema é quando eu gero o .apk

Comment: @AndersonSouza, se puder, coloque seu `build.gradle` (descaracterizando dados sensíveis) e o `AndroidManifest` também.

Comment: Anderson, vi que você usa dois `keystore's` diferentes... Dentro do `build.gradle` esta usando o `android.jks` e no `keytool` esta usando o `debug.keystore`. Esses arquivos possuem o mesmo conteúdo? Para testar a troca, você precisa apagar os dados do app!!

Comment: Eu sei lá... kkk
android.jks é a mesma coisa que debug.keystore?
Posso usar o keytool com android.jks?

Comment: Não é a mesma coisa não, só se o conteúdo for o mesmo. Dê uma olhada, mas você deveria usar o mesmo `keystore`, no caso o `debug.keystore` nos dois lugares. Use o `debug.keystore` porque você já configurou ele no `Developer Console`, troque o que está no `build.gradle`.

Comment: Cara regerei a chave utilizando o android.jks:
keytool -list -keystore C:\Users\Anderson\AndroidStudioProject
s\Lisandro\android.jks

Fui la no google console e gerei outra chave, coloquei na aplicação, desinstalei tudo no celular, instalei de novo e segue o mesmo problema! ;/

Comment: Não deu, está dando o mesmo problema!

Comment: To ficando sem idéias, vou ver isso depois com calma, estou de saída agora. Mas tente atualizar a versão da sua dependência do `google play services` pra `com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+` como na documentação: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html. Aproveita pra adicionar as regras do `Proguard` mesmo que não esteja usando ainda (`runProguard false`).

Comment: Cara funcionou!!! Muito obrigado pela sua dedicação e comprometimento em querer me ajudar! Valeu mesmo!
Muito Obrigado!

Comment: A solução foi:
Quando for utilizar o keytool para gerar a chave e colocar lá no google console, utilize a mesma chave no build.gradle da sua aplicação.
show de bola!

Comment: @AndersonSouza, coloquei uma explicação como resposta caso alguém venha a ter esse problema. Se tiver algo faltando sobre a solução final pode editar ou sugerir alguma mudança.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A solução encontrada para o problema, durante diversas tentativas de possíveis erros, é a utilização sempre que possível do mesmo certificado para todos os `builds`.**

Caso isso não seja possível ou desejado, é preciso registrar cada certificado (seja um para `release`, outro para `debug` ou qualquer que seja o critério usado) com o par: **<fingerprint do certificado*>:<nome.do.pacote>** na seção **Public API** do projeto no **Google Developers Console**.

Isso também é importante se estiver usando os `flavors` do Gradle, onde o apk final terá um sufixo ou prefixo no nome do pacote.

Para gerar o **fingerprint** basta usar:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore
```

Nesse caso específico:

Quando testava seu app em modo `debug`, estava usando uma chave para o `build debug` que tinha o acesso registrado no console do Google.

Mas quando ia gerar seu **apk** no `build release` estava usando outro certificado, que não estava no console do Google, o que ocasionava o problema de autenticação.